# Crystal Report in php

Tags: php, com, crystal-reports

How I can create a crystal report in php kindly guide me so that I can make it possible. I have tried a lot of code and tutorials but un-usefull for me.

I have tried

```
$COM_Object = "CrystalReports12.ObjectFactory.1";
$my_report = "C:\\Report2.rpt";
$ObjectFactory= New COM($COM_Object);
$creport = $ObjectFactory->OpenReport("c:\\report2.rpt", 1);
```

Here is the error is

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method com::OpenReport()

any one can help me i m very thankful for that preson

Comment: You should first search on stackoverflow using its search feature. Anyways, since you are a new user, i have posted the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

Use XML + XSL:FO with Apache FOP via PHP-JavaBridge.

Here is how: http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/HowTo/PHPJavaBridge

PostScript would be nice!